# Estimation with adding-up constraints when the constraint is a coefficient

Tags: constrained-regression

I have a variable $Y_i = Y_{1,i} + Y_{2,i} + \cdots + Y_{n,i}$. Specifically, $Y_i$ is a measure of consumption for an individual $i$ and $Y_{1,i},Y_{2,i},\cdots$ are consumption expenditures on various subcategories for that individual.

Following an individual and exogenous income shock $X_i$, I am interested in how individuals change total consumption $Y_i$ as well as spending on the various subcategories.

That is, I am interested in the coefficients $\beta,\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n$ from estimating
$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i$$
and 
$$Y_{1,i} = \alpha_1 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_{1,i}$$ 
$$Y_{2,i} = \alpha_2 + \beta_2X_i + \epsilon_{2,i}$$ 
$$ . $$
$$ . $$
$$Y_{n,i} = \alpha_n + \beta_nX_i + \epsilon_{n,i}$$

**My question is**: What is the most efficient way of obtaining estimates of $\beta,\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n$? Is it to estimate the system equation by equation, or can I use the constraint $\beta=\beta_1+\beta_2+\cdots+\beta_n$ in some intelligent way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of goods is exhaustive and one of them is "savings" then you would have $\beta_1 + \ldots + \beta_n = 1$ (i.e. all new income is allocated to the purchase of some good or else saved).

You could then use such restriction to improve the estimation of your betas, although if the number of goods is large the improvement would likely be modest.